# How do I sum instances of a categorical value without using table in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aggregate, heatmap, r-table

I want to add up the number of times a value appears based on another value. Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(hour = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "2", "3"), name = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B"))
```

Using table (`table(df$hour, df$name`) gives me exactly the right output but I don't want a table - I want to do a heat map in ggplot and need a dataframe. I have been pulling my hair out - there has to be an easy way.

Answer (score 4):

The table output can be converted to data frame.  Use one of these depending on the output desired:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))

library(tibble)
rownames_to_column(as.data.frame.matrix(table(df)), "hour")

as.data.frame(table(df))
```

### heatmap

Regarding heatmaps note that `heatmap` in the base of R accepts `table` output directly (and also gplots::balloonplot not shown here accepts table output):

```
heatmap(table(df))
```

It can also be done in ggpubr::balloonplot, lattice::levelplot or ggplot2 using `as.data.frame(table(df))`:

```
library(ggpubr)
ggballoonplot(as.data.frame(table(df)))

library(lattice)
levelplot(Freq ~ hour * name, as.data.frame(table(df)))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  table %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hour, name, fill = Freq)) + geom_tile()
```

The output looks like this (see Note at end for code that generated this):

[image]

### Note

```
df <- structure(list(hour = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "2", "3"), name = c("A", 
"B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

library(cowplot)
library(gridGraphics)

heatmap(table(df), main = "heatmap")
# convert from classic to grid graphics to later combine
grid.echo()
p1 <- grid.grab()

library(ggpubr)
p2 <- ggballoonplot(as.data.frame(table(df))) + 
  ggtitle("ggubr::ggballoonplot")

library(lattice)
p3 <- levelplot(Freq ~ hour * name, as.data.frame(table(df)), 
  main = "lattice::levelplot")

library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

p4 <- df %>% 
  table %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hour, name, fill = Freq)) + geom_tile() + ggtitle("ggplot2")

plot_grid(p2, p3, p4, p1, nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to do a heat map in ggplot and need a dataframe.

An option might be `stat_bin_2d()`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(hour, name)) +
  stat_bin_2d()
```

Result

[image]

From `?stat_bin_2d`:

> Divides the plane into rectangles, counts the number of cases in each rectangle, and then (by default) maps the number of cases to the rectangle's fill.